# PackagesNotFoundError on conda for pytorch

Tags: pytorch, conda

I want to install Pytorch 1.12 version, the CUDA version is 11.3, the python version is 3.9.18. Using the command as the following:

```
conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/  pytorch==1.12.0 torchvision==0.13.0 torchaudio==0.12.0 cudatoolkit=11.3 -c pytorch
```

But, it reports the error:

```
(DL) C:\Users\daiyij>conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/  pytorch==1.12.0 torchvision==0.13.0 torchaudio==0.12.0 cudatoolkit=11.3 -c pytorch
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - torchvision==0.13.0
  - pytorch==1.12.0
  - torchaudio==0.12.0

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/pytorch/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/pytorch/noarch
  - https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/free/win-64
  - https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/free/noarch
  - https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/free/win-64
  - https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/free/noarch
  - https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/cloud/conda-forge/win-64
  - https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/cloud/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/anaconda/cloud/menpo/win-64
  - https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/anaconda/cloud/menpo/noarch
  - https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/anaconda/cloud/bioconda/win-64
  - https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/anaconda/cloud/bioconda/noarch
  - https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/anaconda/cloud/msys2/win-64
  - https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/anaconda/cloud/msys2/noarch
  - https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/anaconda/cloud/conda-forge/win-64
  - https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/anaconda/cloud/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/cloud/msys32/win-64
  - https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/cloud/msys32/noarch
  - https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/cloud/pro/win-64
  - https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/cloud/pro/noarch
  - https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/cloud/pytorch/win-64
  - https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/cloud/pytorch/noarch
  - https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://pypi.doubanio.com/simple/win-64
  - https://pypi.doubanio.com/simple/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

And I also add the other channels like tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn, the current channel as the following:

```
(DL) C:\Users\daiyij>conda config --show channels
channels:
  - https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/free/
  - https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/free/
  - https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/cloud/conda-forge/
  - https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/anaconda/cloud/menpo/
  - https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/anaconda/cloud/bioconda/
  - https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/anaconda/cloud/msys2/
  - https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/anaconda/cloud/conda-forge/
  - https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/main/
  - https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/main
  - https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/cloud/msys32/
  - conda-forge
  - https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/cloud/pro
  - https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/cloud/pytorch
  - https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/pkgs/main/
  - https://pypi.doubanio.com/simple
  - defaults
```

Nvidia Cuda version:

```
(DL) C:\Users\daiyij>nvcc -V
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2021 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sun_Mar_21_19:24:09_Pacific_Daylight_Time_2021
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.3, V11.3.58
Build cuda_11.3.r11.3/compiler.29745058_0
```

How can I solve this problem? Many thanks